# EF4 adding multiple entities (An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager)

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have a object with a lot of properties on it. A bunch of these large object are to be inserted in the db but with only one property on them changing. The property that will be changing is not the primary key. First time SaveChanges succeeds but the subsequent ones fail with "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.....". Here is the flow in code:

```
    //create the entity and set the properties that don't change
    TheLargeObject obj = new TheLargeObject();
    obj.Prop1 = 
    obj.Prop2 = 
    ...
    obj.Prop20 = 

    //create a list of values that differ between each entity
    List<int> validIds = new List<int>();

    private static void SaveToDatabase(TheLargeObject obj, List<int> validIds)
    {

        foreach (int id in validIds)
        {
            //this is the only property that changes
            obj.KeyId = id;

            //make a copy - do we really need this?
            TheLargeObject newobj = new TheLargeObject();
            newobj = obj;

            using(Entities objContext = new Entities())
            {
                objContext.TheLargeObjects.AddObject(newobj); //ERROR: An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.  
                objContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm just starting out with EF4, so I'm probably going about this in the wrong way.
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure what your trying to do here. Mainly this statement confuses me:

> A bunch of these large object are to be inserted in the db but with only one property on them changing.

How can a **new** object (ie inserted) be **changing**? If it's new, what is there to change?

All of the entities in your model have an **EntityKey**, which is usually the primary key on the database-side.

What i think your doing is doing `.AddObject`, when you should be doing `.Attach`.

Here's how you **INSERT** a new object:

```
var newFoo = new Foo();
ctx.Foos.AddObject(newFoo);
newFoo.SaveChanges();
```

Here's how you **UPDATE** an existing object:

```
var existingFoo = ctx.Foos.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1); // or however you want to get it
existingFoo.Name = "Changed foo";
newFoo.SaveChanges();
```

Or if you have a **detached** entity:

```
var existingFoo = new Foo();
existingFoo.Name = "Foo name";
ctx.Foos.Attach(existingFoo);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

So, **i think** in your example, your code should simply be:

```
objContext.TheLargeObjects.Attach(newObject);
objContext.SaveChanges();
```

In a nutshell, if you have an entity which you are positive already exists in the database, and you have constructed the entity manually, use `.Attach`. If you have a brand spanking new object, use `.AddObject`.

However, to be safe - you could *go and get the object again*, make the changes you need, then do `.SaveChanges()`.

`.Attach` is usually used in stateless scenarios such as web sites, where objects are not kept in the graph between requests, therefore to make changes we need to `.Attach`, or retrieve the object again before making the changes.

Hopefully this clears it up for you.

Comment: Thanks for replying and aplogies about the confusion. It is going to be a new object, so I want an insert and not an update. So .Attach is not going to work in my case as the entity is not going to be in the db. Creating the object is time consuming (because of the large set of properties) hence I want a way to just change that one property and do savechanges() again. I finally figured the correct way to use the context lifetime and then the .AddObject started working.

Comment: So you got it sorted? What was confusing was your still saying "i want a way to just change that one property", again if it's new object i'm confused what it to be changed? Or do you mean you only want to SET one property of the new object, and add it to the DB. If it's a new object, you should be using `.AddObject`. So is it sorted?

Comment: Yes it is sorted now. I meant SET only one property and send it back to the DB.

Comment: No problems. As a courtesy, please accept this as the correct answer - or if you don't believe it solved your problem then post your own answer. Glad you got it sorted. :)